# How to get full access to one dimension in OpenCV mat?

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, image-processing

Ok, My problem is not accessing one element from the mat, but I want to get the whole mat while one dimension is fixed. Let's say we have a three dimension matrix and I want to access the third dimension which should return a rows*cols mat.
In matlab, this is extremely easy, say A is a three dimension matrix(3*3*3), if we want to access the the third dimension, then just use A(:,:,1), A(:,:,2) A(:,:,3). But how should we do in OpenCV? It seems that OpenCV didn't provide this method?
I am asking this because I have a vector of Mat: Vector frames, each element in the vector is a two dimension gray image. I want to change the vector format into a three-dimensional Mat format. But I just don't know how to copy it. The ideal way should be:

```
for(int i=0; i<frames.size(); i++) {
    A(:,:,i) = frames[i].clone();
}
```

How should I do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To answer your specific question on how to combine 3 channels into one image, you would use [`merge`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#void%20merge(const%20Mat*%20mv,%20size_t%20count,%20OutputArray%20dst)) like so:

```
merge(frames, A);
```

For the more general question of how to access 2D planes of a 3D Mat, hopefully [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv) will give you some insight. Specifically how the `B`, `G` and `R` components of a Mat are interleaved on each row like so (they have a much better image in the tutorial):

```
      | Col 1  |  Col 2  |  Col 3  |  Col 4  |...
Row 1 |B  G  R | B  G  R | B  G  R | B  G  R |...
Row 2 |B  G  R | B  G  R | B  G  R | B  G  R |...
Row 3 |B  G  R | B  G  R | B  G  R | B  G  R |...
...
```